# The difference between 'AND' and '&&' in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, logical-operators

Is there a difference in the way SQL interprets the logical operators `AND` and `&&`?

Comment: You can use && and `and` in conjunction with each other. `WHERE title='cabbage' && type='vegetable' OR title='cherry' && type='fruit'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For mySQL: The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//logical-operators.html#operator_and) is not saying it explicitly, but they are listed as identical:

> **AND, &&**
>
> Logical AND. Evaluates to 1 if all operands are nonzero and not NULL, to 0 if one or more operands are 0, otherwise NULL is returned.

The [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) page also makes no distiction.

Answer (score 32):

`AND` is Standard SQL

`&&` is proprietary syntax

Answer (score 9):

If you're working with PostgreSQL, '&&' means overlap (have elements in common):

example: `ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: I just noted the 'mysql' tag, so my answer does not relate specifically to the OP, but I think this might be still useful for people landing on this page.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387129.aspx they have the same functionality in SQL Server.

MySql has this to say on the subject http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: That's not SQL Server syntax, that's Entity SQL syntax (from the Entity Framework). SQL Server only supports the standard SQL operator `AND`, not `&&`.