# PHP hash SHA256 login password (different from normal)

Tags: php, hash

This is my function to hash password on registration page.

```
function hashPassword($orgPassword){

srand(date("s")); 
$chars = "abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; 
$salt = ""; 
$num = strlen($chars); 
for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){ 

    $salt.= $chars[rand()%$num];
} 
$hashedPassword = "\$SHA\$".$salt."\$".hash('sha256',hash('sha256',$orgPassword).$salt);
return $hashedPassword;
}
```

This is my php for login.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['user_password'];
$salt = "";
$hashed = "\$SHA\$".$salt."\$".hash('sha256',hash('sha256',$password).$salt);
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "mypassword", "testdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){

    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$username' &&  user_password='$hashed'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if ($count==1){

    echo "success";
}else {

    echo "Invaild Username Password";
}   

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But login.php always give me "Invaild Username Password".

Thank you reading If you want to know more detail please ask because I'm not very well to explain in English.

I'm Thai but I will try to explain as best as I can.

Comment: Was the hashed password properly/successfully in DB to start with?

Comment: yes user_name in user table is "test" user_password is "$SHA$q89MR18YmTCmSVt$005634ce378b6d2bb85a8ee3f0d5370d82fa2cbf2733add106319c0d70a4849e"

Comment: Check to see if the column's length is long enough to accomodate the hash. Many times, that is the reason, or a contributing factor. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Btw, I don't know if you're aware of this, but there are 2x UNICODE characters just before `a4849e` at the end of the hashed string, which could also be a problem. It may appear as `70‌` but it's not. I suggest you look into using PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an empty `$salt` in your login. The strings arent equal.
Additionally, you'd be better off using [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). Get the stored password based on the users name and compare the stored hash that way.

Comment: Where I should put     [crypt()][1]    Thanks

Comment: I'am sorry. It was supposed to be a link to the documentation of crypt. Now you can click it. There you'll find everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write `$hashed=hashPassword($password)` to hash the user input?

EDIT: Your function uses random numbers and will generate a different hashed code everytime. To fix this, you should probably use inbuilt hash functions like `sha512()`. You can find a list of such functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Comment: *"'AND' and not '&&' in the SQL Query."* - `&&` and `AND` do the same thing. Both are valid. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105692/

Comment: It pays to search/research first. Google is everyone's friend, from beginning to end ;-)

Comment: How to do that? I'm new to php Thanks

Comment: @FIFATanathan: How to do what? I've just used your function hashPassword to hash the user input and compare it to the value in database.

Comment: I replace ///$hashed = "\$SHA\$".$salt."\$".hash('sha256',hash('sha256',$password).$salt);/// with ////$hashed=hashPassword($password)///// but it's also display "Invaild Username Password"

Comment: Have you included the file which contains the hashPassword() function?

Comment: You probably need to echo out all 4 things here, input username and password and database username and password and check them manually. May be there's something wrong with the entries inside the database

Comment: Oh why I'm using the same hash in login.php and register.php but in login.php it's give me ////$SHA$$49dc52e6bf2abe5ef6e2bb5b0f1ee2d765b922ae6cc8b95d39dc06c21c848f8c//// In database ////$SHA$J2WhdQszkGCnh7Q$794c00d1bb7cb83d7b9a85bf2a31803d35f44f60007799256261a68e92d1f776////

Comment: Because you are using random numbers inside your hashed function. You should probably use the in-built sha512 function for hashing.

Comment: I've tested something and found that every time the hash always generate different sha256 code. Maybe this is why it isn't same in database. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Edited my answer. Use default functions like sha512() to hash your password at both ends.

Comment: Use sha512 to hash sha256 right? Hash user input and hash password from database and compare it.