# PHP datatables: How to apply Extra where sql condition

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, datatable

I want to apply this sql:

```
"select id, user_id FROM members_profile WHERE online='1'"
```

to my this datatable:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable( 
{
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "aProcessing": true,
    "aServerSide": true,
    "ajax": "includes/onlinenow_hdl.php",
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        "zeroRecords": "No records available",
        "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
} );
```

Can you please help me out to add where condition in my `onlinenow_hdl.php`. Thanks..

Comment: to me it's not clear what you're asking for. Can you alter/specify your question?

Comment: the answer to your very last question would be `select id, user_id FROM members_profile WHERE online=1 AND other_condition=$x`, but I doubt that's what you meen.

Comment: `WHERE online='1' AND othercondition = ...`

Comment: Sir.. I have seen in datatable only do the sql query as
`select column1,column2 FROM table name`. and it dont take any additional query condition after `where`. How can i add condition to datatable...?

Comment: Please add the PHP code you have in *onlinenow_hdl.php*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `AND` ?

```
"select id, user_id FROM members_profile WHERE online='1' AND offline='0'"
```

Or

```
"select id, user_id FROM members_profile WHERE online='1' && offline='0'"
```

The first one is preferred as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105658/the-difference-between-and-and-in-sql) said.

As I know Datatables doesn't care what your query is. But response given by your code in order to display it to table.