# MySQL - Using REPLACE() In WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, where-clause

I know that I can `SELECT` data in a column by using `SELECT REPLACE(colm, ' ', '') FROM tbl` to replace all spaces, but how can I do this in a `WHERE` clause? Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT things.*, stores.* 
FROM things, stores 
WHERE things.id = 283468234 
&& 
stores.name = "Some Name" 
&& 
REPLACE(LOWER(stores.owner), ' ', '') = "firstnamelastname"
```

An example of the result I want is:

```
|  things.id  |   stores.name    |     stores.owner     |
|-------------|------------------|----------------------|
|  283468234  |    Some Name     |  First Name Last Name|
```

The error I'm getting is:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`

Note: I have also tried using `AND` instead of `&&` but nothing changed

I think the reason I get this error is due to PHPMyAdmin automatically removing my last `&&` statement, and adds in `LIMIT 0, 25`, making the query `SELECT things.*, stores.* FROM things, stores WHERE things.id = 283468234 && stores.name = "Some Name" && LIMIT 0, 25`. Is this the issue or is it my query? How can I fix this?

Comment: Adding `&& LIMIT 0,25` would cause any query to error out as that is nonsense. phpmyadmin is not adding `&&`. Perhaps switch your `&&` over to `AND` and see if that clears it up.

Comment: @JNevill made an edit, sorry abotu that

Comment: The error is related to you adding `&& LIMIT...`. Now that you changed the code, what's the output? Remember to change the question according to what you keep trying

Comment: What do you mean "Automatically removing your last &&`? Is the SQL you have in your question the EXACT sql you are submitting? I agree that Phpmyadmin is probably adding `LIMIT 0,25` to your statement, but that's NOT what is causing the error.

Comment: @JNevill meaning it turns into `SELECT things.*, stores.* 
FROM things, stores 
WHERE things.id = 283468234 
&& 
stores.name = "Some Name" 
&& 
LIMIT 0, 25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Looks like it's purely a bug with PHPMyAdmin. I tried running the query with my software and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is equivalent to `AND` in SQL.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105692/5129424

Make sure LIMIT is the very last clause in your SQL statement.
Your use of LIMIT is incorrect as well. You want:

`LIMIT 25` for 25 results returned
not `LIMIT 0, 25`
(results 0 through 25 was your intent, I assume).

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Putting that all together from your original statement:

```
SELECT things.*, stores.* 
FROM things, stores 
WHERE things.id = 283468234 
AND stores.name = "Some Name" 
AND REPLACE(LOWER(stores.owner), ' ', '') = "firstnamelastname"
LIMIT 25
```

That should work, though I have not tested it.

Comment: The problem is that PHPMyAdmin automatically adds `LIMIT 0, 25`. I also tried using `AND` instead of `&&` but I got the same error

Comment: @apxx Have you tried running the query outside of PHPMyAdmin? Build a quick script to connect and run the query and see what you get back. Have you also looked into writing an explicit OUTER JOIN instead of your query? That may also be part of the problem. I'm not willing to accept the error at face value at this point. Also, don't use .* - try selecting the explicit columns you want from each table.