# How can I display data from a SQL database to a textbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently searching, how can I put or display data from my database through a textbox that will be used to submit to a different table later on.

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from subjects_main where Course='$c' && YearLevel='$d'");
if(!$query)
{
    die("Error in Table");
}
```

Comment: please try to discribe in more detail what you want to do

Comment: What you're asking is off-topic for a few reasons. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: sorry guys I'm kind of new here, will take the advice tho thanks for your time, god bless

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not provide enough information. From what I have understood well, then you can use `var_dump()` to show all data (from sql query) - e.g. in the code below.

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from subjects_main where Course='$c' && YearLevel='$d'");
if(!$query)
{
    die("Error in Table");
}
else
{
    var_dump($query);
}
```

When you use Laravel framework, you can use `dd` to show all data (from sql query).

**P.S. - You have a bug in sql query - change `&&` to `AND`**

Why?  `AND` is Standard SQL `&&` is proprietary syntax.

Read this information on page: [The difference between 'AND' and '&&' in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105658/the-difference-between-and-and-in-sql)

Comment: *"P.S. - You have a bug in sql query - change && to AND"* - That isn't a bug and is perfectly valid syntax in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html - It's also not what the question is about.