# Wrongly selecting decimal values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with decimal values.

```
start_value decimal(10,2) | end_value decimal(10,2)
```

This is my MySQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE start_value  >= '1.05' && end_value <= '1.05'
```

Above query produce zero results but in my database, there is a value 1.00 – 1.49

And if I change the query to just select the first value like below

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE start_value  >= '1.05'
```

MySQL is displaying a wrong result. It will display 1.5 and 1.99 when it should be displaying 1.00 – 1.49

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please setup a DB fiddle / SQL fiddle with the relevant sample data and showcasing your exact issue.

Comment: You realize that `1.00 >= 1.05` is false, right?

Comment: `start_value decimal(10,2) | end_value decimal(10,2)` are these values mean something?

Comment: do we have `&&` in sql? I cannot recall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105658/the-difference-between-and-and-in-sql

Comment: @AkhilaMadari decimal(10,2)  is the datatype in my table.

Comment: @AkhilaMadari `&&` and  `AND` is the same operator.

Comment: @ally I don't think they are same

Comment: If you want values between 1.00 and 1.49 then you write `start_value  >= 1.00 AND end_value <= 1.49`. If you want right answers to come out [you need to put right values in](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/charles_babbage_141832).

Comment: @JJJ if you want to give the exact value you do need to using greater then or less then operators far as i know.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to find with the query? Every range that contains 1.05? Then the operators are the wrong way around: you'll need `start_value <= 1.05 AND end_value >= 1.05`.

Answer (score 0):

Here when you are providing the range you need to provide your start and end value correctly.For the values you have given it can be  queried as follows

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE start_value  >= '1.00' and end_value <= '1.50'
```